# Is there a general term for a class field starting with an underscore that are for internal use by a getter/setter of the same name?

Tags: terminology

Why I need this is a long story, basically it boils down to naming a variable.

Anyway, a basic example in js:

```
class my_class {
    constructor(some_value) {
        this._internal_thing_1 = Math.floor(some_value / 3);
        this._internal_thing_2 = some_value - this._internal_thing_1 * 3;
    }

    get banana() { return this._banana; }
    set banana(v) { this._banana = v; }

    get pear() { return this._pear; }
    set pear(v) { this._pear = v; }
}
```

So I'd call all the fields starting with "_" as internal variables or something along those lines. Doesn't have to be an underscore, it just seems trendy.

However, what do you call _banana and _pear? They are internal, sure, but what sets them apart is that they are used sorta like backing for a specific getter/setter pair. I need a name that's more specific to them, a defining name that doesn't include _internal_thing_1 and _internal_thing_2.

Comment: in python, when we use two underscores like ```__this``` we call them "dunders."  Dunder-this, dunder-that, etc.

Comment: "what sets them apart is that they are used sorta like backing for a specific getter/setter pair" Exactly correct. That is the naming convention. It's just a convention, but so widespread that in some languages certain features actually depend on it; in Objective-C, if you have a property `myProp`, the instance variable that backs it must be called `_myProp` or your program won't work properly. There is no specific name for the underscore version or for this convention as a whole.

Comment: @TomLubenow I looked into that, apparently the word dunder comes from "double underscore", i guess that would make single underscore "sunder"? sounds pretty cool at least